# Непонятный синтаксис

Tags: c++, c++11

Зачем нужен данный синтаксис, ведь тип результата не вычисляется автоматом?

`auto foo(int arg) -> int {}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Этот синтаксис появился в результате включения в стандарт C++ лямбда-выражений.

Лямбда-выражение может быть записано, например, как,

```
auto foo = [](int arg) -> int { /*...*/ };
```

Это лямбда-выражение может быть преобразовано в функцию, имеющую тип `int( int )`

Этот синтаксис переняли для объявления функций. У функции в ее начале должен присутствовать спецификатор(ы) типа возвращаемого выражения.  Так как реальный тип возвращаемого значения указывается после списка параметров, то в качестве спецификатора возвращаемого значения в объявлении функции используется спецификатор `auto`.

В приведенном вами примере большого смысла так объявлять функцию не имеется. Но иногда тип возвращаемого значения может зависеть от типа вычисления сложного выражения, определить который программисту самостоятельно бывает трудно, да и это может привести к ошибке.

Поэтому этот синтаксис удобен, например, при объявлении шаблонных функций.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class U>
auto foo(const T &x, const U &y) -> decltype( x + y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;

        std::cout << typeid(foo(x, y)).name() << std::endl;

        long z = 30;

        std::cout << typeid(foo(x, z)).name() << std::endl;

        float f = 40;

        std::cout << typeid(foo(x, f)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль, например, в MS VC++ может выглядеть как

```
int
long
float
```

Заранее сказать, какой будет тип возвращаемого выражения, невозможно. Он зависит от типов параметров функции и от типа вычисляемого выражения. Использование спецификатора типа `auto` в данном примере облегчает объявление функции.

Answer (score 6):

- Он нужен, в частности, для того, чтобы поместить тип возврата в тот контекст, где видны имена параметров функции, соответственно, известна их семантика. Например

  ```
  auto foo(short a, short b) -> decltype(a + b) { ... }
  ```

  В данном случае компилятор учтет тот факт, что операнды выражения `a + b` будут подвергнуты integral promotions и [на большинстве платформ] дадут результат типа `int`. В то же время на платформах, где integral promotions для `short` дают `unsigned int` тип возврата функции автоматически станет `unsigned int`. (Желательна такая "гибкость" или нет - зависит от контекста.)
- Также при определении метода класса за пределами определения класса такой тип считается находящимся в области видимости класса, что влияет на процесс поиска неквалифицированных имен

  ```
  typedef void *Ret;

  struct A {
    typedef int Ret;

    Ret foo();
    Ret bar();
  };

  auto A::foo() -> Ret { return 0; } // OK, `Ret` обозначает именно `A::Ret`
  Ret A::bar() { return 0; } // Oшибка - `Ret` обозначает `::Ret`
  ```

  При использовании "классического" синтаксиса в определении пришлось бы указывать квалифицированное имя типа `A::Ret`.

  Особенно существенно синтаксис с `->` упрощает запись при определении методов шаблонного класса за пределами класса, ибо квалифицированное имя шаблонного класса может быть очень длинным, да еще и требовать указания ключевого слова `typename`.
- При использовании этого синтаксиса вы получаете возможность пользоваться "компактной" записью составных типов (аналогично тому, как это делается в `using` вместо `typedef`)

  ```
  auto foo() -> int (*)[20] { ... }
  ```

  В "классической" записи это выглядело бы как

  ```
  int (*foo())[20] { ... }
  ```

  что многие сочтут менее удобочитаемым вариантом.

Comment: Так а почему `decltype` впереди не написать?

Comment: @user239213: "Впереди" у вас не будет доступа к имени `arg`.

Answer (score 5):

Ну, в первую очередь для шаблонов. Компилятор же может не знать возвращаемый тип до того, как увидит аргумент? Например,

```
template<class T>
???  f(const T& t)
{
    return t*5.0;
}
```

Что тут поставить вместо `???`? А вдруг T - это класс с переопределенным оператором умножения? который возвращает объект другого класса?

А вот так

```
template<class T>
auto  f(const T& t) -> decltype(t*5.0)
{
    return t*5.0;
}
```

никаких проблем...

Comment: C#, например, вполне справляется: `T MaxBy<T>(IEnumberable<T>seq, Func<T, double> selector)`.

Comment: @VladD Но мы же говорим о C++ :)

Comment: Ну, раз C# может подглядеть вперёд и понять, что такое `T`, то и C++ мог бы подглядеть вперёд и разобрать декларацию вида `decltype(t*5.0) f(const T& t)` правильно.

Comment: @VladD по-моему Ваш пример не показателен. Т.к. `T` и `decltype(t*5.0)` могут быть разными типами.

Comment: @VladD: Исторически установившиеся правила name lookup языка С++ требуют, чтобы в такой ситуации компилятор глядел *назад*, а не вперед. Т.е. в `int t; template<class T> decltype(t*5.0) f(const T& t) {}` компилятор *обязан* найти именно предыдущее `int t;`. Поэтому переход на "глядение вперед" в таком случае не сводится к простому "мог бы поглядеть", а является фундаментальной переделкой правил name lookup языка, переворачивающей все с ног на голову.

Comment: @AnT: Ну, насчёт фундаментальности я бы поспорил. Например, в методах класса можно обращаться к полям даже перед их текстовым объявлением. Так что смотреть вперёд компилятор умеет. Так что если бы при введении `decltype` уточнили, что lookup в объявлениях имеет право смотреть вперёд (как в классах), думаю, это не сломало бы обратную совместимость.

Comment: @VladD: Не совсем понимаю, что именно вы предлагаете изменить. Во-первых, в данном случае речь идет не о смотрении "вперед" или "назад", а о качественной смене *scope*, в которой производится поиск имени. В определениях методов классов ничего подобного не происходит. Наоборот, "смотрение вперед" в определениях тел методов делается для того, чтобы *избежать* смены scope.

Comment: Во-вторых, если бы предлагаемый вами "разворот" для правил name lookup сделали только для аргумента decltype, то получилась бы довольно странная каша из разных правил lookup для разных частей спецификации типа возвращаемого значения. Такого дикого ада никто в здравом уме, разумеется, не допустил бы. А если изменить правила для всей спецификации возвращаемого типа - то накроется медным тазом вообще все, ибо поведение в этом контексте действительно фундаментально и завязка на него в существующем коде существенна.

Comment: @AnT: Не то, чтобы я предлагал что-то изменить, что вы. Я не являюсь опытным разработчиком языков. Мне кажется, что можно было бы name scope для декларации функции сделать всю декларацию функции, а не только прочитанный к текущему моменту кусок. Вот и всё «изменение». Оно параллельно к тому, что name scope для декларации класса — вся декларация класса (а не только прочитанный к текущей точке кусок). // Мне кажется, что такое изменение не поменяло бы смысл кода, написанного до введения `declspec` — или это не так?